# Can my apartment management stop me having visitor friend with pet? not overnight

Tags: rental-property

We do not have anything mentioned in the lease about pets. I have moved in this apartment from 2015 and just last year they sent out pet policy changed and , no pets allowed.
My friend visited me with her small dog for few hours and the manager contacted me directly with the pet removal notice. I am not sure if he is doing that to charge me for extra money or something? because few hours dog was just sleeping and there is none property damage. I just need to know what Can I do if he do want me to charge fees. If it's legal for him to do or not.

Comment: This depends on where you live.  Laws are different in New York, Texas, Paris, etc.

Answer (score 1):

> Can my apartment management stop me having visitor friend with pet?
> not overnight

Absent a local statute or ordinance to the contrary, or Americans with Disabilities Act (ADA) considerations (e.g. for seeing eye dogs), yes, your apartment management can stop you from doing this if the lease authorizes them to do so.

It sounds like the original lease from 2015 that didn't prohibit pets was changed at the time of a lease renewal in this case, which landlords are usually allowed to do.